# how to login on oddsportal.com with just python's requests module?

Tags: python, python-requests

This is my code.
Post method's status code is 200.
But, when I look at printed content it shows that I'm still on pre-login page.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0'
}

login_data = {
    'login-username': 'username',
    'login-password': 'password'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'http://oddsportal.com/login/'
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests

data = {
    'login-username': 'test',
    'login-password': 'test',
    'login-submit': ''
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0'}

r = requests.post("https://www.oddsportal.com/login/",
                  data=data, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

Output confirming that the code on right track since i don't have a valid user/pass:

```
    <div class="message-error">
        <ul>
                                        <li>Wrong username or password.</li>

                                                    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried to log in with my real credentials, and I didn't find my username in the output content/text